# trouble aligning html headers and td cells

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a small table which can scroll when there are many tr tags under the headers. I have managed to get it to work correctly with just one column but I am struggling to get it to work with more than one column as the columns do not align. It is important that the size of the table stay what it is since I am adding new rows using jQuery and auto scrolling.

I just want the columns of the thead and tbody to align...

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.grid_background_comm {
  background-color: rgb(173, 173, 173);
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 950px;
  height: 90px;
}

.grid_background_comm thead {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 950px;
}

.grid_background_comm th {
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 950px;
}

.grid_comm {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  width: 950px;
  height: 85px;
}

.grid_comm tr {
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  display: block;
  width: 935px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.grid_header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_comm" class="grid_background_comm">
  <thead>
    <th id="1" class='grid_header'>Line</th>
    <th id="2" class='grid_header'>I/O</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="gv_comm_data" class="grid_comm">
    <tr>
      <td headers="1">01</td>
      <td headers="2">02</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display:block is attached to thead and tr which is affecting their default behaviour. You could remove them
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/zYGKqZL

```css
.grid_background_comm {
  background-color: rgb(173, 173, 173);
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 950px;
  height: 90px;
}

.grid_background_comm thead {
  text-align: left;
  width: 950px;
}

.grid_background_comm th {
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 950px;
}

.grid_comm {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  width: 950px;
  height: 85px;
}

.grid_comm tr {
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  width: 935px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.grid_header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_comm" class="grid_background_comm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th id="1" class='grid_header'>Line</th>
    <th id="2" class='grid_header'>I/O</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="gv_comm_data" class="grid_comm">
    <tr>
      <td headers="1">01</td>
      <td headers="2">02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td headers="1">01</td>
      <td headers="2">02</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td headers="1">01</td>
      <td headers="2">02</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td headers="1">01</td>
      <td headers="2">02</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use your help along with some tweaking to get my tbody section correct except (I made just one row for testing) the row I have is being stretched the full height of tbody instead of just a smaller row height. Any ideas on how to make the tr's a fixed height. Setting their height seems to have no effect.

Comment: nvm. I changed my method and was able to achieve what I wanted with div tags instead of tables. thank you!